# Technologies to create SPA

Tags: web, web-applications, single-page-application, multi-page-application

Good day guys. 
I have a task to create a SPA. 
As I understand, [streamlabs](https://streamlabs.com/) and [streamelements](https://streamelements.com/) are SPA. Here is the question - what technologies i have to use to create something similar?

Answer (score 0):

That is a very broad question. You can check here for available frameworks and associated technologies:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application